# SSRS IE8 JavaScript Error Invalid Character ScriptResource.axd

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reporting-services, scriptresource.axd

A colleague of mine has produced various reports in SSRS. We have 2 machines in the office that are failing to load the report via Internet Explorer 8. Both machines are returning a JavaScript error at the Reports 'Loading' screen.

On these particular machines, the reports load fine in FireFox so I am guessing that it is IE related. Both Machines are running IE8.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The JavaScript error detail is as below:-

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 20 Jan 2012 09:44:17 UTC

Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Reports_2/ScriptResource.axd?d=dz2_T_-skCIGFrM350LrrgpIbuyQ3hv0Po2nyTqnjMC_h2orbb8AW34-wlapNOlKQn3w_65Hv8xicNrMgbLAWsuKLkB24a0JnVTM3AD64R_ELK1K6KpCKGgYkO_evQ1uY6IeQkuEpQDrHclftKpS0G8rnJM1&t=4d63fd9d

Message: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: The script '/Reports_2/ScriptResource.axd?d=dz2_T_-skCIGFrM350LrrgpIbuyQ3hv0Po2nyTqnjMC_h2orbb8AW34-wlapNOlKQn3w_65Hv8xicNrMgbLAWsuKLkB24a0JnVTM3AD64R_ELK1K6KpCKGgYkO_evQ1uY6IeQkuEpQDrHclftKpS0G8rnJM1&t=4d63fd9d' could not be loaded.
Line: 5
Char: 25312
Code: 0
URI: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Reports_2/ScriptResource.axd?d=3Ai4085hE-J-y-0xbpoDUETOM6YJ4KTxATxoi5MUC6t3_pBfPhudsCfAT2Zo0EYhCJ53VN7b1CMlJVAjSV173nFtwGNqRGEOxEQ5oaE1x1fJu9GYkrDUg931CJbqHdCdhmahc5Hew8HZppPb3veIO20e1DrsUcF2kvQowgeCkHgVZ1EA0&t=4d63fd9d

Comment: Can you post the relevant JavaScript?

Comment: Only what is relevant please...

Comment: The full error is posted. AFAIK no javascript is being used in the report itself. The problem is, IE is retunring a Javascript or 'script' error on the loading screen.

Comment: Does the report work correctly on other computers also running IE8?

Comment: Yes it does. There are 10 PC's working absolutely fine. The other 2 don't work, reporting this error in IE (in the status bar, JS error) which leads me to believe it is not a server configuration issue but a PC configuration issue ????

Comment: Have you checked neither/all IE8's run/don't run in compatibility mode?

Comment: Are you accessing the reports via another application through the .NET ReportViewer control?

Comment: @bububaba Nothing to do with compatibility mode. Tried with it Enabled/Disabled on both PC's to no avail.

Comment: @Etch No it is not being accessed via the .NET ReportViewer control AFAIK. Just the standard Web Viewer that comes with SSRS as default. It is however some kind of ReportViewer control.

Comment: To add, reports run fine in Firefox on both these machines, so it seems that is is IE related.

Comment: Check what toolbars they have in the add-on's. I used to support SSRS with a company of 1,300 employees and we had a couple of cases where an IE add-on was causing problems with the ReportViewer control. I don't know why exactly, but just that it was and we were able to remove the interfering add-in's to resolve.

Comment: Can you post related ASP.Net ASPX/CS codes.?

Comment: @Bharath there are no 'relevant codes' this is a STANDARD install of SSRS with a simple report pulling from a seperate sql database.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using SQL Server 2005?

If so make sure you have all of these installed on your server hosting reporting services. (Also if you ever happen to have a website with a .NET reportviewer control in it it will need these patches as well)  [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933137)  Also make sure all the normal security patches are applied to your SQL server namely this one.  [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4685#filelist) and this one.  [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9756)

This may fix your problem outright. There have been all kinds of updates to the Report Viewer 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package that have fixed a few wonky bugs I have come across.

Comment: Will try this. Server is SQL Server 2008 AFAIK. Why would patching the SERVER affect 2 lone PC's whilst others work perfectly fine ???

Comment: @generalexception Though I dont have a 100% answer for that question, when I implemented SQL RS at my last job I had all kinds of problems with viewing the reports.  They would work perfectly on a dev environment and would work for some in a staging environment.  Until we synced both the DB server and web servers(we used reportviewer control in a .net app) with the redis packages and appropriate patches. We would get odd inconsistent results, similar to your situation.  But alas, I using SQL Server 2005, so I am not sure if those patches and redis packages still apply.

Comment: Disabling script compression <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="false" enableCaching="true"/> doesn't work either.

Comment: The ReportViewer is served out by the report server, which is typically not installed on the same server as the database engine. You only need to patch the report server to upgrade the ReportViewer control. Just FYI, the SSRS report manager is an ASP.NET web forms application. ScriptResource.axd is a server side component you'll find with any web forms application. It is used to manage all of the client scripts associated with the various web controls on the form as well as the ASP.NET infrastructure client code used to manage post backs.

Comment: @tnktnk you are 100% right.  I guess the setup I was using before was the SQL RS on the same box as the DB so I referred to it as so, but I agree that wasnt as helpful for the explanation.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

IE Bug, typically not fixed on Windows XP

Discussed here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/a32b665a-916a-43af-862b-2205f8efe083

Indicated it is fixed here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980182

Comment: thanks for this, affected PC's are running IE 8.0.6001.18702 but after installing KB980182 the issue still exists.