# SSRS Reports IE8 ScriptResource.axd compression/decompression error

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, scriptresource.axd

Following on from this question:

[SSRS IE8 JavaScript Error Invalid Character ScriptResource.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939854/ssrs-ie8-javascript-error-invalid-character-scriptresource-axd)

This is an issue that I really need a resolution for. I have more information now regarding this and therefore have decided to log a new question.

I have a suite of SSRS reports located on a SQL Server running SQL Server 2008 R2. I have had no issue whatsoever accessing these reports using Internet Explorer for over 6 months.

Last week someone logged a helpdesk call stating that she could not see the reports as the page loads forever and a small icon with an explanation mark appears in the bottom left corner after a few seconds with the text 'Done' next to it.

As I was already aware that this issue was probably an IE problem, I advised the user to download Firefox and just use that instead. Upon doing this the user could see the reports.

The next day I went to access the reports as normal using IE, and the problem the user had encountered, was happening to me. I was stuck in an infinite loop with the small ‘Done’ with errors image in the corner. The error message upon clicking was:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 11 Sep 2012 09:58:13 UTC


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://xxxxx/xxxxxxx/ScriptResource.axd?d=iYyn-VGIBSAJxmoeImLsTtesAMP1500Akt1KNGOHN_b-PEkCEZq1v-qs_SbiV610TRrm-8ISgq4xWAV6lxRrv1NaHOGFuUUOfusDmQgdb8FPNvi0YU9Sc8hp24nzIzpdQXiEtHcT-lcQIUkU_kcJg-EM61o1&t=ffffffffb868b5f4


Message: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: The script '/Reports/ScriptResource.axd?d=iYyn-VGIBSAJxmoeImLsTtesAMP1500Akt1KNGOHN_b-PEkCEZq1v-qs_SbiV610TRrm-8ISgq4xWAV6lxRrv1NaHOGFuUUOfusDmQgdb8FPNvi0YU9Sc8hp24nzIzpdQXiEtHcT-lcQIUkU_kcJg-EM61o1&t=ffffffffb868b5f4' could not be loaded.
Line: 5
Char: 25340
Code: 0
URI: http://xxxxx/xxxxxxx/ScriptResource.axd?d=IcCsSJUAEsxazITdzqHjDt1BesfkTp6Mm3HS3LIMBVF2Lxr_e3gi3u2PvZQRuLbGfe0MhIoDqlxXvrXTRXhpV2wfNhWcJK0iLFPtfDZzuej4KzvCBV1ggWWCaLYj6iG0RpVkSYBY-IrbRMKNOCn9Qc8W77bR9CrIphFmFbR2zKerE3DA0&t=ffffffffb868b5f4
```

I checked the IE version number that I was using was version 8.0.6001.18702. I tried getting a colleague to attempt to access the report who was also using version 8.0.6001.18702 IE, and hers went through no problems.

The thing I find strange about this is that for 6 months plus I have no issues, then all of a sudden I cannot use IE to access the reports, and you can’t even say it’s an internet explorer version issue because as I said, my colleague is using the same version as me.

As it works using Firefox it still points towards an IE issue however possibly something Server side?

Can anyone suggest anything here as if it’s a problem for me, this could become a problem for many users over night.

See attached screen shot with what I see when I try to access the report:

> [image]

**UPDATE:**
Research suggests this should fix, have done this and monitored using fiddler however it is still using GZIP compression, and not working for me.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="false" enableCaching="true"/>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Is it like this for all reports or just some?

Comment: A few tips for debugging and adding info to the question. Tell us more about the differences between your and your colleague's PC, in particular OS version (incl. SP), security settings for IE, the browser mode IE goes into, the charset IE believes the page is in. If all that fails you can dive deeper into the request and response from/to those two PC's and compare those.

Comment: Both on Windows XP, both running Verion 5.1.2600, both have default security settings on IE

Comment: I downgraded to IE7 yesterday, I could view the reports, I then re-installed IE8 but the release candidate 1 version with zero updates, the problem was there again. Strange as I used ie8 for months with no issues...

Comment: Hi Select, what is the Operating System, Webserver you are hosting the site on?

Comment: Does it happen when you open IE without extensions?

Comment: @bhupendra patel 2008 r2 is the Operating System on the server side.

Comment: @BartekR Have tried this, have also tried Reseting all Internet Explorer settings in the advanced tab to no avail.

Comment: All the forumns suggest using this in the web.config file for ReportServer. See update to question. P.S Still does not work.

Comment: We think this is a gzip, deflate problem with IE8, see here for further reading:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472874/ie8-not-sending-accept-encoding-gzip-deflate

Comment: Another update, I deselected use http 1.1 Settings in Internet Options and the reports loaded up, this is not an ideal solution though as other pages may not load up correctly - Does anyone have another fix to this whilst using http 1.1 Settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As crazy as this sounds, the solution to my problem was simple.

Go to Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced

Turn off HTTP 1.1 Settings and then back on again.

The SSRS Reports now render correctly, however my version of ie8 still does not want to support gzip encoding wheras my collegues does.

**UPDATE**
After 10 minutes - 30 minutes the error comes back however, I have now turned off HTTP 1.1 all together and although not ideal, I can view the reports.