# IE8 not sending Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, gzip

Following on closely from this question [SSRS IE8 JavaScript Error Invalid Character ScriptResource.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939854/ssrs-ie8-javascript-error-invalid-character-scriptresource-axd) I have done some debugging and narrowed the issue down to a gzip, deflate problem.

We have various machines with IE8 installed on them. The problem is, some installations of IE don't seem to add the Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate to the HTTP Request header when requesting a JavaScript resource via ScriptResource.axd.

Here is the HTTP request off machine 1 (works fine):

```
GET http://10.x.x.x6/Reports_2/ScriptResource.axd?d=dz2_T_-skCIGFrM350LrrgpIbuyQ3hv0Po2nyTqnjMC_h2orbb8AW34-wlapNOlKQn3w_65Hv8xicNrMgbLAWsuKLkB24a0JnVTM3AD64R_ELK1K6KpCKGgYkO_evQ1uY6IeQkuEpQDrHclftKpS0G8rnJM1&t=4d63fd9d HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAJIAAAAYABgAqgAAABgAGABYAAAAEAAQAHAAAAASABIAgAAAABAAEADCAAAAFYKI4gYBsR0AAAAP5M9BpXhDtQyLRxQO0MslBkQARQBOAEIASQBHAEgAUwBIAEkAUgBFAGEAbAB5ADgANgA3ADcANwBEAEMAQwAwADEAOQA4ADgAOAAW1o72sWx0hAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8+dJyp0KpjG5sP9WUlmrk4FptdhpYQAEETsImSmR+ZzMapF8Z91Wv
Host: 10.x.x.x6
```

And here is the same request made off machine 2 (doesn't work as its returning gzipped data):

```
GET http://10.x.x.x6/Reports_2/ScriptResource.axd?d=dz2_T_-skCIGFrM350LrrgpIbuyQ3hv0Po2nyTqnjMC_h2orbb8AW34-wlapNOlKQn3w_65Hv8xicNrMgbLAWsuKLkB24a0JnVTM3AD64R_ELK1K6KpCKGgYkO_evQ1uY6IeQkuEpQDrHclftKpS0G8rnJM1&t=4d63fd9d HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-gb
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2)
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIIAAAAYABgAmgAAABgAGABIAAAAEAAQAGAAAAASABIAcAAAAAAAAACyAAAABYKIogUBKAoAAAAPRABFAE4AQgBJAEcASABTAEgASQBSAEUAagBvAG4AOQA0ADYAMQA0AEQAQwBDADAAMQAzADUANgA2APyGLo3yOcCnAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABccpJT8TohKqbhq3PzWDPApr1NmEypAPg==
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Host: 10.x.x.x6
```

The problem seems to be that IE is not-requesting gzipped data, but its actually getting gzipped data from the server (an then its failing because it doesn't think its gzipped).
If i manually decompress the data returned using zcat or something, i can view the returned JavaScript fine.

What would cause IE8 not to add this header onto the request ??

Comment: The User-Agent string on the first request seems to be saying that it is IE9, not IE8.  But, more fundamentally, the server has to follow the rules.  If the client doesn't say it can accept gzipped data, the server mustn't send it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston agreed. I used IE9 just as an example. Whats funny is that eventhough the request does not contain Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate the server (which is an SSRS server) still returns gzipped data. Whats even stranger is, if we switch off HTTP 1.1, and then switch it back on again, the server seems to send uncompressed data then and follows the rules. Secondly, whats strange is that IE8 on my colleagues machine seems to send the Accept-Encoding header, whereas IE8 on a few other machines (all based on the same disk image) doesn't.